# Django 1.7 import error: no module named mysite

Tags: django, apache

I am a newbie to Django, trying to test run with Apache and mod_wsgi with Windows.

This is my httpd conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /hm "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite/mysite">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Allow from all
AddHandler wsgi-script .py

</Directory>
```

I have this project structure:

```
  mysite
      -manage.py
      -mysite
        -settings.py
        -wsgi.py
```

In my wsgi, I have:

```py
import os, sys 

base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    
sys.path.append(base +"\\mysite" ) 
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Why do I get `import error: no module named mysite` ?

Comment: Could you show the project structure more clearly? I can't tell from how you have it spelled out if you have two directories called `mysite` (and whether they are nested)

Comment: Yes, I have a mysite directory in mysite. Please see uppdted.